# Difference between 7446,47 etc

Tags: integrated-circuit, 7segmentdisplay, ttl

I have looked in the data sheets, as well as the TI article, but I am still unsure of the answer to this question:

> What is the practical difference between a 7446 ("BCD to 7 segment decoder/driver with 30V open collector outputs"), a 7447 ("BCD to 7-segment decoder/driver with 15V open collector outputs"), a 7448 ("BCD to 7-segment decoder/driver with Internal Pullups"), and a 7449 ("BCD to 7-segment decoder/driver with open collector outputs").

To drive a normal 7 segment LED common-cathode display, can I use any of them? If not, what are they for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'46 and '47 are for common-anode LEDs, whereas '48 and '49 are for common-cathode LEDs.

For the common-anode types, '46 allows a higher drive voltage than '47.
For the common-cathode types, the difference between '48 and '49 is that '48 has "ripple-blanking input" (for suppressing leading zeroes), which the '49 has not.

There also are '246, '247 and '248 types that work like the above mentioned ones, but use a slightly different display pattern for "6" and "9" (namely with "tails").

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to list the differences. Refer [this pdf](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls47.pdf) for detailed information.

$$ \begin{array}{rcccc}
    \style{color:blue}{\textbf{}} & \style{color:blue}{\textbf{7446}} & \style{color:blue}{\textbf{7447}} & \style{color:blue}{\textbf{7448}} & \style{color:blue}{\textbf{7449}} \\
    \style{color:blue}{\textbf{Active level}} & \mathrm{low}   & \mathrm{low}   & \mathrm{high}  & \mathrm{high} \\
    \style{color:blue}{\textbf{Output config}} & \mathrm{open\ collector} & \mathrm{open\ collector} & \mathrm{internal\ pullup} & \mathrm{open\ collector} \\
    \style{color:blue}{\textbf{Max Voltage}} & 30V   & 15V   & 5.5V  & 5.5V \\
    \style{color:blue}{\textbf{Pins}} & 16    & 16    & 16    & 14 \\
    \style{color:blue}{\textbf{Lamp Test}} & \mathrm{Yes}   & \mathrm{Yes}   & \mathrm{Yes}   & \mathrm{No} \\
    \style{color:blue}{\textbf{Blanking input}} & \mathrm{Ripple} & \mathrm{Ripple} & \mathrm{Ripple} & \mathrm{Direct} \\
\end{array}%
$$